# Get computed observable dependencies

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say that I have a viewmodel which looks something like this:

```
this.foo = ko.observable();
this.bar = ko.observable();

this.bah = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var bar = this.bar();
}, this);

this.baz = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var foo = this.foo(),
        bah = this.bah();
}, this);
```

Is there any way to access the dependencies of a computed observable dynamically? In the example above with `baz`, I would like a list with `foo` and `bar`, since they are the two observables that can trigger the computed.

I need this for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no documented or public API to get this information. In addition, I think (though am not sure) that internally KnockoutJS works the other way around: an observable knows who are dependent on it ("subscribers"), as opposed to the dependency knowing about the observables it depends on.

The only thing that comes close is `baz.getDependenciesCount()`, but that only gives you a number. You can check out [the relevant source file](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/dependentObservable.js) to see what other things computeds expose.

The only other option that might help: include the unminified / debug version of KnockoutJS, and use the debugger to dig into the underlying problem.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to know what observable that triggered the computed as well? I looked at the `computedContext` but couldn't find anything useful there...

Comment: @filur Incidentally, I recently [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38604988/419956) with a "negative" to that exact question.